# How to create a hierarchy of abstract classes with EF code first migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am in the process of refactoring my domain entities to allow a distinction between standard Domain Entities and Aggregate Root Domain Entities. Both of these abstract classes inherit from DomainEntity.

My AggregateRootDomainEntity class holds no database columns it currently stores my domain event collection as domain events should only be raised against an aggregate.

My problem is now when I try and create a database migration I get the following error: -

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'DomainEntityAggregateRoot' cannot be instantiated, and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateClrInheritance(IModel model, IEntityType entityType, HashSet`1 validEntityTypes)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateClrInheritance(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelRuntimeInitializer.Initialize(IModel model, Boolean designTime, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 validationLogger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'DomainEntityAggregateRoot' cannot be instantiated, and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type.
```

I've read articles on Table-per-concrete-type and have included the following code but this has no impact and I get the same error: -

```
builder
    .UseTpcMappingStrategy()
    .ToTable(TableNames.Prefix + TableNames.Users);
```

The full code is as follows: -

```
public abstract class DomainEntityRoot
{
    protected DomainEntityRoot(Guid id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.LastUpdated = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        this.IsActive = true;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public Guid? ModifiedUserId { get; set; }
}
```

```
public abstract class DomainEntityAggregateRoot : DomainEntityRoot, ICommonDomainEntity
{
    private readonly List<DomainEvent> domainEvents;

    protected DomainEntityAggregateRoot(Guid id)
        : base(id)
    {
        this.domainEvents = new();
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<DomainEvent> GetDomainEvents() => this.domainEvents.ToList();

    public void ClearDomainEvents() => this.domainEvents.Clear();

    protected void RaiseDomainEvent(DomainEvent domainEvent)
    {
        this.domainEvents.Add(domainEvent);
    }
}
```

```
public class User : DomainEntityAggregateRoot
{
    private User(Guid id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }

    private User(
        Guid id,
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        string email)
        : base(id)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.Password = string.Empty;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Status = UserStatus.AwaitingConfirmation;
        this.TwoFactorEnabled = true;

        this.RefreshTokens = new HashSet<RefreshToken>();
    }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

    public string? TwoFactorSecret { get; set; }

    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }

    public string? RegistrationConfirmationToken { get; set; }

    public string? ResetPasswordToken { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? ResetPasswordTokenExpires { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }

    public bool CanAuthenticate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.IsActive && this.Status == UserStatus.Trustworthy;
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{this.FirstName} {this.LastName}";
        }
    }

    public static User Create(
        Guid id,
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        string email)
    {
        var user = new User(
            id,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email);

        user.RaiseDomainEvent(new UserRegisteredDomainEvent(Guid.NewGuid(), user.Id));

        return user;
    }
}
```

```
public sealed class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IdentityCache? identityCache;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IdentityCache identityCache)
        : base(options)
    {
        this.identityCache = identityCache;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        this.SaveChangesInternal();

        var result = base.SaveChanges();

        return result;
    }


    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        this.SaveChangesInternal();

        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return result;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(AssemblyReference.Assembly);
        modelBuilder.ApplySoftDeleteQueryFilter();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void SaveChangesInternal()
    {
        this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        var entries = this.ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(x =>
                x.State == EntityState.Modified ||
                x.State == EntityState.Added ||
                x.State == EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            if (entry.Entity is ICommonDomainEntity entity)
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                {
                    entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                    entity.IsDeleted = true;
                }

                entity.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.ModifiedUserId = this.identityCache?.UserId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly if I flatten the hierarchy out to two levels by duplicating the properties DomainEntityAggregateRoot everything works fine!

Comment: please paste code of your DbContext

Comment: Hi, I thought I could side-step this issue but it has now caused me problems further down the line so I've realised the real answer is to try and resolve this original problem, apologies for the delay!

Comment: Just watched a video by the Entity Framework team and they mentioned a bug in EF7 preview 5 whereby you can't create the inherited class as abstract. This seems to only affect the 2nd level of hierarchy so if you just have a single base class then it works. Curious I simply removed the abstract keyword and now I can add my migration!! However, it did then create the DomainEntityAggregateRoot class as an entity but this was easily rectified using modelBuilder.Ignore<DomainEntityAggregateRoot>(); within onModelCreating.